# Sum of one attribute for all instances inside the method in Python

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes, instance

so i have this class:

(i have some variables before)

```
class Phases:
    """Phases properties"""

    def __init__(self, name, volume, density, foc):
        """initialize phase properties"""

        self.name = name
        self.volume = volume  # m^3
        self.density = density  # Kg/dm^3
        self.foc = foc
        if name == "acquatic biota ":
            self.kp = pow(10, logkbio)
            self.zvalue = self.kp * density / h
        else:
            self.kp = koc * foc
            if name == "air ":
                self.zvalue = 1 / (r * t)
            elif name == "water ":
                self.zvalue = 1 / h
            else:
                self.zvalue = self.kp * density / h
        self.zivi = self.zvalue * volume



air = Phases("air ", 24000000000000, 0.00119, 0)
water = Phases("water ", 1200000000, 1, 0)
soil = Phases("soil ", 2280000000, 1.5, 0.02)
sed = Phases("sediment ", 24000000, 1.5, 0.04)
susp = Phases("suspended solids ", 12000, 1.5, 0.04)
bio = Phases("acquatic biota ", 1200, 1, 0)
```

So, the problem is that i want a new variable called sumzivi that represent the `sum (air.zivi, water.zivi, soil.zivi, sed.zivi, susp.zivi, bio.zivi)`.

I tried making a new list but if I do the list, the list is after my object definement.. i need the sum to be inside the method because after the sum itself, i need to put another attribute that uses the sumzivi and also other previous attributes (like this:
`self.mol = sumzivi * self.volume / h`)

is it possible? Or do you suggest not to use classes and to manage these data in a different way?

Thank you so much, sorry for the dummy coding but i'm an environmental scientist approaching coding for the first times...

I have to create many methods like this one so i'm searching for the easiest and fastest way to do it, thank you <3

Comment: in the question, where is this `zivi` variable that you speak of introduced into the code ?  or what is it ?  usually might expect this to be one of the `arguments` into the `Phases` class, based on the question.

Comment: Is a derived attribute, derived from the attributes self.zvalue and self.volume.. i didn't put in the argument of Phases, i didn't know it's needed, how to do that in case? In the method it is the last attribute